# Compute the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}{e}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}{e}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$.
I tried adding $1$ and subtracting $1$ so I can use $1^\infty$ case.

Comment: You should just take taylor expansions in the numerator $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ and denominator $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Comment: @GuusPalmer i dont know Taylor expansions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Consider the limit of the logarithm:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln\left(\left(\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}{e}\right)^\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\
\frac{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}-1}{2x}$$
where at the last step we used L'Hopital's rule.

What is the limit $L$ as $x\to 0$? Then required limit would be $e^L$.

Comment: oh i get it now

Answer (score 3):

Taking the logarithm,
$$\frac{\dfrac{\log(1+x)}x-1}x=\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x^2}=\frac{x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\cdots-x}{x^2}\to-\frac12$$

Hence

$$\frac1{\sqrt e}.$$

---

As you didn't learn the Taylor expansion, use L'Hospital like Robert Z showed.

Answer (score 1):

I computed the limit: $$\lim_{x\to0}\bigg(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}}{e}\bigg)^{1/x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}.$$

Comment: ummmm how did you do it?